# Trouble with canvas in custom Joomla module

Tags: javascript, canvas, joomla

I am building a custom Joomla module and I'm trying to display an image with canvas. Here's the code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function drawXpBar() {
     var xpPlot = document.getElementById('xpBar').getContext('2d');
     var img = new Image();
     img.onload = function() {
     xpPlot.drawImage(img,0,0);
     }
     img.src = 'images/xpBarBg.png';
     }
window.onload.drawXpBar();
</script>
```

However, when the page renders the image does not appear. I have entered the code using sorcerer and it is within the {source} block. When I use inspect element in Chrome it is showing me error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'drawXpBar' of null." Doesn't that mean that it thinks the function has not been defined? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[window.onload = funcRef;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload)

```
window.onload = drawXpBar(); //call function on window load event
```

Comment: I've tried that and I get error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null drawXpBar"

Comment: @Maverick575 post you html too.

Comment: You know what? I actually just read elsewhere that the javascript has to go AFTER the canvas. I just moved the code and now it is working. I think I tried that before, but because I had window.onload.drawXpBar(); it wasn't working. Thanks to your response, and a little digging, the canvas is now working properly. Thanks!